# Exporting to excel all browsers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

I found script, but it did not work all browsers. I want to use javascript. So, I found the code below. How to i work in microsoft edge and explorer.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell you a simple solution

add one button in the page where table is

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Export Data to Excel</button>
```

now add the below given scripts to the same page

```
<script src="js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
 <script>
      $(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
           $("#tableID").table2excel({
             exclude: ".noExl",
             name: "Excel Document Name"
           });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Do not forget to download jquery.table2excel.js and add this to js folder

Comment: This code will works on IE7+, Firefox and Chrome.But what is the error is view.

Comment: it did not work mozilla firefox,Only a blank page is opening.